# Round button wispform embed button

Tags: html, css

I have created this form using Wispform, I have fixed it on the bottom right of my webpage but I am not able to get it rounded. Where do I add my border radius?
[Something like this](https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FshnoQ.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F30967633%2Fhow-to-create-a-circle-button-in-the-right-bottom-corner-on-android-5&tbnid=GcIqviYITABYdM&vet=1&docid=5cwJnlYozMh3sM&w=1080&h=1920&hl=en-in&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)

```css
.feedback {
  background-color: #31B0D5;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 400px; */
  border-color: #46b8da;
  /* border-bottom-left-radius: 33px; */
}

#mybutton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5vh;
  right: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 40vw; */
}

.sendimg {
  max-width: 20px;
  /* height: 1vw; */
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://dashboard.wispform.com/plugin/buttonPopup/index.js?v=1"></script>
<div id="mybutton">
  <button class="feedback wispformPlugin-buttonPopup" data-name="samyakvermani" data-id="445e1461">
            <img src="images\send-email.png" class="sendimg" alt="send">
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: show a screenshot of how you want to round the button

Comment: Like a circle, I am not even able to round the borders, that would help too. [I want something like this](https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FshnoQ.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F30967633%2Fhow-to-create-a-circle-button-in-the-right-bottom-corner-on-android-5&tbnid=GcIqviYITABYdM&vet=1&docid=5cwJnlYozMh3sM&w=1080&h=1920&hl=en-in&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim)

Comment: I gave the answer. Was it necessary?

Comment: Thank you so much. What do two classes together mean? like ```.one.two{...}```

Comment: Your tag contains two classes `feedback` and `wispformPlugin-buttonPopup` - `class = "feedback wispformPlugin-buttonPopup"`. And in order to have an exact reference to the CSS, these classes must be written together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a selector and add this selector to css with the following rules:

```
.feedback.wispformPlugin-buttonPopup {
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: auto;
}
```

```css
.feedback {
  background-color : #31B0D5;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 400px; */
  border-color: #46b8da;
  /* border-bottom-left-radius: 33px; */
}

#mybutton {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5vh;
  right: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 40vw; */
}
.sendimg{
  max-width: 20px;
  /* height: 1vw; */
}

.feedback.wispformPlugin-buttonPopup {
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://dashboard.wispform.com/plugin/buttonPopup/index.js?v=1"></script>
    
<div id="mybutton">
  <button class="feedback wispformPlugin-buttonPopup" data-name="samyakvermani" data-id="445e1461">
              <img src="images\send-email.png" class="sendimg" alt="send">
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please help me how can I change shadow width for the button?

Comment: Thanks, this worked but the button is oval and not circular can we fix that?

Comment: Yes, of course, this rule in css is responsible for the shadow - `box-shadow: rgb (200 200 200) 0px 2px 25px 1px`, in the selector `.wispformPlugin-buttonPopup`. What color and width do you need to make?

Comment: I used ```-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px red);
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px red);```, but this does not change the width of the shadow just the color.

Comment: No, it is not that oval but it is not a perfect circle. It is like a little spread from the sides, like oblonge.

Comment: I made the shape work by adjusting padding on top and bottom, but I am not able to fix the width of the shadow.

Comment: This is how you can adjust the width of the shadow. - https://ibb.co/SrzVV05

Comment: this does not even change color of the shadow. The one I mentioned however changes the color only and not the width.

Comment: But it works for me. - https://ibb.co/Zx6kRKm. Try `!important`.

Comment: Thanks! Changing rgb() to color name worked, also for the width. Thanks a lot! Happy new year!

Comment: Happy to help. Happy New Year!